# Creating a markdown parser with ANTLR

Tags: markdown, antlr4

I am an ANTLR newbie. I am trying to implement a markdown to HTML translator.

These are the grammar and the associated files that i coded.

**Grammar**

```
grammar markdown;

prog    :   stat+;

stat    :   main_heading
        |   sub_heading
        |   custom
        |   italic
        |   bold
        |   bolditalic
        |   text
        |   WS
        ;

text    :   TEXT|SPACE;

main_heading: text* WS '='+ WS+;

sub_heading : WS? text* WS '-'+ WS+;

custom      : '#'+ text* WS; //to support custom headings

italic  :   ('*'stat*'*')|('_'stat*'_');

bold    :   ('**'stat*'**')|('__'stat*'__');

bolditalic: ('***' stat* '***');

TEXT    :   [a-zA-Z0-9]+;

SPACE   :   ' ';

WS      :   [\t\r\n]+;
```

**Visitor Method**

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.*;

import java.util.Objects;

public class markdownEvaluator extends markdownBaseVisitor {


    @Override
    public Object visitItalic(markdownParser.ItalicContext ctx) {
        int i=1;
        System.out.print("<i>");
        while(ctx.getChild(i)!=null)
        {
            visit(ctx.getChild(i));
            i++;
        }
        System.out.print("</i>");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object visitBold(markdownParser.BoldContext ctx) {
        int i=1;
        System.out.print("<strong>");
        while(ctx.getChild(i)!=null)
        {
            visit(ctx.getChild(i));
            i++;
        }
        System.out.print("</strong>");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object visitBolditalic(markdownParser.BolditalicContext ctx) {
        int i=1;
        System.out.print("<strong><i>");
        while(ctx.getChild(i)!=null)
        {
            visit(ctx.getChild(i));
            i++;
        }
        System.out.print("</i></strong>");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object visitSub_heading(markdownParser.Sub_headingContext ctx) {
        int i=0;
        System.out.print("<h2>");
        while(ctx.getChild(i)!=null)
        {
            visit(ctx.getChild(i));
            i++;
        }
        System.out.print("</h2>");
        System.out.println();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object visitCustom(markdownParser.CustomContext ctx) {
        int headernumber = 0;
        int i=0;
        while(Objects.equals(ctx.getChild(i).getText(), "#"))
        {
            headernumber++;
            i++;
        }
        System.out.print("<h"+String.valueOf(headernumber)+">");
        while (ctx.getChild(i)!=null)
        {
            visit(ctx.getChild(i));
            i++;
        }
        System.out.print("</h"+String.valueOf(headernumber)+">");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object visitMain_heading(markdownParser.Main_headingContext ctx) {
        int i=0;
        System.out.print("<h1>");
        while(ctx.getChild(i)!=null)
        {
            visit(ctx.getChild(i));
            i++;
        }
        System.out.print("</h1>");
        System.out.println();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object visitText(markdownParser.TextContext ctx) {
        System.out.print(ctx.getText());
        return null;
    }
}
```

1. How correct is my markdown grammar? Are there better methods of specifying it?
2. How can I improve the way in which the code is generated? Presently I am using a while loop to check if the nodes have a child and then respond accordingly. Are there better methods to do this? Are there other methods that ANTLR supports that i can use to create the same effect?
3. We want the HTML code to be written on to a file. So Is there a way to automatically create a file and write <html> when the program starts parsing and append </html> and close the file when the parser finishes the parsing?

Thanks.

Comment: Compare your grammar with the existing ones, such as https://github.com/mar9000/antmark and also use its test cases to assert your grammar's correctness.

Comment: You will find a pretty comprehensive set of tests here: https://github.com/michelf/mdtest

Comment: IMHO there is no need for `bolditalic`.